# Error while creating multi series chart in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to plot multi-series chart in excel sheet using VBA.

I want to add these data in tow series.
Series1-> A1:B2 and Series2->A3:B4 ( A on X-axis , B on Y-Axis)
           A        B
     1    Test1     10
     2    Test2     20
     3    Test11    30
     4    Test22    40

I have added below code but facing "Invalid parameters" error

```
Dim ochart As Object, ochartObj As Object
Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
Set ochart = ochartObj.Chart
ochart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ochart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B1:B2")
ochart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("A1:A2")
ochart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("B3:B4")
ochart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("A3:A4")
```

Please help :) Thanks!

Comment: What exact line is the error on? Also could it be because `left:=325` is in lowercase?

Comment: Actually, Make sure SeriesCollection 1 and 2 are filled with something, you get that error when you're trying to access something out of the range of the array.

Comment: @erazorv4 : I am getting error in ochart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B1:B2") line. lowercase left:= 325 is not causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a new series for each one before assigning them values...

```
Dim ochart As Object, ochartObj As Object

Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
Set ochart = ochartObj.Chart

ochart.ChartType = xlXYScatter

ochart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ochart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B1:B2")
ochart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("A1:A2")

ochart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ochart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("B3:B4")
ochart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("A3:A4")
```

Also, I would suggest that you declare your objects as their specific types.  It makes the code be a bit more efficient, and you'll have the benefit of the IntelliSense.  Accordingly, your code could be re-written as follows...

```
Dim ochart As Chart, ochartObj As ChartObject, oSeries As Series

Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
Set ochart = ochartObj.Chart

With ochart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    Set oSeries = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With oSeries
        .XValues = Range("B1:B2")
        .Values = Range("A1:A2")
    End With
    Set oSeries = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With oSeries
        .XValues = Range("B3:B4")
        .Values = Range("A3:A4")
    End With
End With
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ::Thanks for the reply.! perfect.. your suggested code has worked for me.:) Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ochart As Object, ochartObj As Object
Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
Set ochart = ochartObj.Chart
ochart.ChartType = xlXYScatter

ochart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ochart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

ochart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B1:B2")
ochart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("A1:A2")
ochart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("B3:B4")
ochart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("A3:A4")
```

But you really should:

```
Dim ochart As Excel.Chart, ochartObj As Excel.ChartObject
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. the code suggested by Domenic has worked for me.